# Why does the Sobel function for edge detection fail to find the contour of a white square in a black background?

Tags: image-processing, octave, edge-detection, sobel

[image: Square BW (uint8)]

I tryed to apply to the image the following code in octave:

```
sq = imread("Square BW.jpg"); 
figure(1), imshow(Square);

cont1 = edge(sq,"Sobel");
figure(2), imshow(cont1);
```

The image I get is:

[image: Edges (logical)]

And a similar image appears if I use the Prewitt function. Can anyone explain to me what is happening? The problem is that I can't visualize the process only the result, so I can't understand why the code isn't working.

Comment: You probably need to play with the [`threshold` parameter](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html).

Comment: Try `imshow(cont1, [])` to scale the displayed image properly.

Comment: This seems to be an issue in Octave.  In MATLAB, I get the perimeter around the square, but in Octave I can't seem to get the same results.

Comment: @rayryeng Can you  capture the threshold in the second output parameter in each case and see what they are? I suspect Paul R is correct and the threshold is being computed differently.

Comment: @beaker - That's a good idea.  One moment.

Comment: @beaker - It looks like the thresholds are being computed differently.  In Octave, the threshold is `4*M` where `M` is the mean of the gradient image.  In MATLAB, they compute Sobel slightly different, but they take `sqrt(4*M)` as the threshold.  I had to open up the MATLAB script to figure this out.  In Octave, their threshold is mentioned in the docstring.

Comment: @rayryeng So to get Octave to behave the same way as matlab we just have to run sobel, get the threshold, take the square root and pass it back in to sobel again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be how threshold is computed in Octave. You can see how Octave does it by looking at its source by entering `type edge` at the Octave prompt, or [online](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/image/file/faa0a913015f/inst/edge.m) (I'm not copying the exact code since the code is GPL -- although quite simple)

To get the border, you will need to set the threshold yourself (hopefully, in future versions of Octave's image package this will be fixed but at the moment it's Matlab incompatible since Matlab documentation on their default is unclear).

Comment: By busting open MATLAB's `edge` function, it boils down to `sqrt(4*M)`, where `M` is the mean of the gradient image, but the way they compute the gradient image for `sobel` is quite different.  There are weights that weight both the horizontal and vertical components, so even then the thresholds don't match up if you take the square root.  BTW, thanks for posting your answer as this pretty much clears up the doubts I had.

Comment: @rayryeng unfortunately, Matlab is copyrighted, so people can't just bust it open and see how it works (at least not if they are interested in writing free software)

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely a problem with the way the threshold is computed, however I wasn't able to find the correct value to use in this picture. After many attempts I found this code that seems to work perfectly:

```
sq = imread("Square BW.jpg"); 
maskSobel = fspecial("sobel");
mSobel = uint8(zeros(size(BW)));
for i = 0:3
  mSobel += imfilter(sq, rot90(maskSobel, i));
end
figure(1), imshow(mSobel);
```

First we create the Sobel matrix/operator and a zero matrix the same size of the image Square BW. Then we rotate the Sobel matrix four times (by 90 degrees),  in order filter the image in all directions (left-right, up-down, right-left and down-up), always adding the result to the mSobel matrix that was created.
Here's the final result:

[image: Result]